# Typing a function with generics and conditinal types

Tags: typescript

I have this function typed

```
export function useKeyData(
  keyName: keyof SomeObjectType,
): string | undefined;
export function useKeyData(): SomeObjectType;

export function useKeyData(
  keyName?: keyof SomeObjectType,
): string | SomeObjectType | undefined {
  const value = { a: 'hello', b: 'hi' } as SomeObjectType;

  const valueToReturn = keyName ? value[keyName] : value;

  return valueToReturn;
}
```

where SomeObjectType is

`type SomeObjectType = { a?: string; b?: string };`

and then when I'm calling useKeyData I get the right return types according to the input

```
const value1 = useKeyData('a'); // value1 type is string | undefined
const value2 = useKeyData(); // value2 type is SomeObjectType
```

The question is, how do I translate this typing to use generics + conditional types in order to save the 2 overloads?

I tried something like this

```
type ReturnedValue<T extends keyof SomeObjectType | undefined> = T extends keyof SomeObjectType
  ? string | undefined
  : SomeObjectType;

export const useKeyData = <T extends keyof SomeObjectType | undefined>(
  keyName?: T,
): ReturnedValue<T> => {
  const value = { a: 'hello', b: 'hi' } as SomeObjectType;

  const valueToReturn = keyName ? value[keyName] : value;

  return valueToReturn;
};
```

But then I get an error in the return statement saying

`Type SomeObjectType is not assignable to type ReturnedValue<T>`

Can someone tell me how can I use generics and conditional types the right way?

Comment: What's wrong with using overloads in this case? It looks like that approach solves your problem nicely, and it has the advantage of being easier to read and to document.

Comment: Yeah I guess it is fine, but I wanted to know how to do it the other way for the sake of learning. I was also curious why the generics and conditional solution doesn't work

Comment: Oh, fair enough then :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes TS struggles to narrow in on a specific type, especially when there is conditionally logic involved. Generally type assertions are considered 'unsafe', but I think they are needed in this case to consume the function optimally. I personally think there are many situations type assertions are ok (eg in library code, simple functions, easily testable functions, etc), but it should be avoided if possible. Here is my solution:

```
export const useKeyData = <SomeObjectType extends Record<string, unknown>, TKey extends keyof SomeObjectType | undefined = undefined>(
  value: SomeObjectType,
  keyName?: TKey
) => {
  return (keyName !== undefined ? value[keyName] : value) as TKey extends keyof SomeObjectType ? SomeObjectType[TKey] : SomeObjectType;
};
```

Note that this function works for other object types, not just `type SomeObjectType = { a?: string; b?: string };` as you have given.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wK6uAaWATwBEBDGYuAXjgB4BlCAW2AHkAjAK2ARgBV8xgcUDGDIAJqjgAlLtDHV0UAJbIA5gBo4GZAGtkEAO7IAfJp558QkCPGSdBCADM49Jm07c+AuAB8t44EcVYDFKfzFA4LFjAAoAKDg4ADdiABsMYAAuF0YWDi5efmB1BLh7fAA5YiYAfmzzAjiASkpjOABvUqhgGAwoZDgY8qqmOABCCiptCKDkELga5LSMgG1h6uAAXThslPTgFuJJBsthUQkyh2dXPI9C70Wb9wKvYBWT7eyn-M8igG44gBfAFxJBoeAidDuMLtODEbIAcgAFsBUqkIAjNKxsgBGABMAGZNHN0CFsrCSSIxAAFKAQMDkwFwJnAuKglDoOCQmAVCAWMJYXAEEhkGLc9xNdngrnAdAAQQF2AsIuIYtlMHcmgARMQtZKwZzuQAhRVCoikVXijja1h6qWG9UVdXzKZK4UWtVQ61wLWUkJ6oA)

Edit:
If you wanted to use overloading, see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCAzgUwNJoJ4BECGU+APACoDyARgFZrSJoAeUaYAJiogEp1wBObYiih8YYAOYAaZGADWYOAHcwAPhUAKODQBciCjTpRpsnAH5d4NmmBi0bAJS79taAG4AUKEiwEydFjxCEmdDBmZWDm5eASERMSkZeSVVaVIAsJZ2ThNsOGA9KhcoDS1qJ0LDYxwnAMcCg2gAbTScAF0PL2h4JFRMHAIiTR1EfDBsKuxdUex7RABvd0REGHz1HMQAXi2ZKxswO1m+NCgQPiRSjyWjk7PEUsac9vcAX3d3CARhRBZhQs35ka6ADkAAs0AAbcFwIHSSi6ACMACYAMzSfbCOy6OaIdEsNgABT4cAADljnohyc8PO9PlBvmhhAA5ODpDZ+PqBQY-KCFew0sBfbkAQX+vQCA3w6m5hWkACJ8LK+R8BXTuQAhUX+fpBKUMnk0OWURX8wV6xl6uyajkS3W-A2IWW4uyKoA). This is not my preference, though, since it involves using `any` type in the implementation. Additionally, depending on the strictness of the TS config and ESLint rules, you may get errors.